# How can I create an object with a given prototype chain?

Tags: javascript

I need a way to create an empty object whose prototype chain is provided as an array of objects:

```
var prototypes = [{one: 1}, {two: 2}, {three: 3}];
var created = create(prototypes);
// prototype chain of created should be:
// created --> {one: 1} --> {two: 2} --> {three: 3}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. The question is clear, and the answer isn't trivially easy to find.

Answer (score 2):

You basically can't (currently*), because there is only *one* prototype chain, prototypes are currently assigned only at object creation, and yet you have multiple discrete objects there that are unrelated. That is, to create the chain, you need each object in the chain to be backed by the previous one, but those aren't.

What you *can* do is create the chain with *copies* of those objects, but of course subsequent changes to those original objects wouldn't be reflected in the chain.

You can get *close* with ECMAScript5 by creating new objects with getters and setters for all of the existing properties on those source objects and syncing them, but that wouldn't handle *new* properties (or deleted ones), just changes to existing properties.

---

* I said "currently" above because the current draft specification for the next ECMAScript version, ECMAScript 6th Edition, has a new `Reflect` object which has the ability to set a prototype on an *existing* object retrospectively. (Whereas with ECMAScript5 and earlier, you can only set an object's prototype when you're creating it.) So as of ES6, you'd be able to assemble those objects into a chain by using the future `Reflect.setPrototypeOf` method. But right now, cross-browser, you can't.

Comment: `Reflect`? Isn't it just `Object.setPrototypeOf`?

Comment: @Bergi: Both are in the current draft (Jan '14). I haven't followed the discussions, but the [reflect page](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:reflect_api) in the Harmony wiki says *"Now that we have modules, a “@reflect” module is a more natural place for many of the reflection methods previously defined on `Object`. For backwards-compatibility purposes, it is unlikely that the static methods on `Object` will disappear. However, new methods should likely be added to the “@reflect” module rather than to the Object constructor."*

Comment: @Bergi: I wonder if `Object.setPrototypeOf` will disappear from future drafts, since it's not in ES5, or if they'll keep it for balance with `Object.getPrototypeOf` (which being ES5 is going to stick around).